# How to show react variable values in loop in table td tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios

i use axios to get values, now i want to display the values in td tag in a loop how to execute it.

my code is :

```
let apiUrl = "http://api_url_here";
axios.get(apiUrl, {headers: headers})
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data[0].provider.firstName);
    //console.log(token);[0]
  })
```

My td code is:

```
<tr>
  <td className="font-weight-medium"> <img className="logo" src={jessica} alt="pam-logo" /> </td>
  <td>jessicajames@gmail.com </td>
  <td>(012)-876789876</td>
  <td>Family Physician</td>
  <td>23145655</td>
  <td>Mountain view,Ave</td>
  <td><Icon icon={editIcon} width="20px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<Icon icon={deleteIcon} width="20px"/></td>
</tr>
```

I need that response.data[0].provider.firstName in 1st td and correspondingly the same for all and it should be in loop to get next iteration.

Comment: Are you using class component for this?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan yes

Comment: Can you show the value of `response.data`?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan its only a json object with name,mail etc

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const myFunction = () => {
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null)

  const apiUrl = "http://api_url_here"

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(apiUrl, {headers: headers})
      .then((response) => {
         setData(response.data)
      })
  }, [])


  return (
    <>
      {
        data && data.map((item, index) => (
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>{item.provider.firstName}</td>
            ...
          </tr>
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `axios` call should ordinarily be in an initialization stage, such as by employing `useEffect` or `componentDidMount`, depending on the style of your component.

Then you set the data using your response, e.g.

```
setData(response.data);
```

or

```
this.setState({"myData": response.data});
```

and in your render, you use that data loop to generate the rows, something along the lines of:

```
const { myData } = this.state;
myData.map((datum, index) => {
   <tr key={index}>
     <td>{datum.provider.firstName}</td>
     ...
   </tr>
});
```

Comment: No its not working, show datum and index is not defined error

Answer (score 0):

If `response.data` is the list with your table content, add this to your `render()` method:

```js
return response.data.map((item, index) => {
   <tr key={index}>
      <td>{item.foo}</td>
      <td>{item.bar}</td>
      ...
   </tr>
});
```

Comment: Was missing a `(`, fixed now